# Theme overrides for custom hook_theme() in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, theming, hooks

I have a custom D7 module which defines it's own `hook_theme()` which defines a few theme functions, of which they define their own template, for example:

```
function foo_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    $items = array(
        'post_foot' => array(
            'template' => 'templates/post_foot',
            'variables' => array('node' => (object)array())
        )
    );
    return $items;
}
```

As you can see, it defines it's own template, which is located in the foo module, in this specific case `sites/all/modules/custom/foo/templates/post_foot.tpl.php`

I'd like to be able to define my own `post_foot.tpl.php` in my theme, and use foo's tpl as a fallback.

Does this happen automagically? Do I need to expand my `hook_theme()` to include overrides?

Answer (score 2):

This should happen automatically. Most core modules define theme hooks which you wouldn't think twice about overriding in your theme. Take a look at node_theme for example http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_theme/7.

The devel themer module should help you out with such things. Needs some work for D7 but should help.

Comment: thanks a lot, I was pretty sure this was just core but couldn't seem to find much documentation about it (which again, made me feel like I was asking silly question) - thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This happens automagically UNLESS your theme hook has a name that is different from the template file, after hyphens have been replaced with underscores. In that case the auto-discovery will fail.

The auto-discovery is based on the name of your module-defined theme hook, not on your module template name. This was a gotcha for me.

In module:

theme hook: foo_theme_hook

template: theme-hook.tpl.php

In theme

template: theme-hook.tpl.php

= FAIL

To fix, in the above example, either rename theme hook to be "theme_hook" instead of "foo_theme_hook" or rename the overriding template file to be "foo-theme-hook.tpl.php"

Comment: I think this is getting close to the problem some might face. Looks like it has to do with the key name matching the template name, where underscores are hyphens. For more info, see the issue here: https://www.drupal.org/node/342350